# How to prove this hard geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The incircle of triangle $ABC$ has center $I$ and touchs the sides $BC,CA,AB$ at the points $D,E,F$ respectively,and Let  the centers of the  excircles tangent to $BC,CA,AB$ be $I_{1},I_{2},I_{3}$ respectively, and the excircles be tangent to $BC,CA,AB$ at $D',E',F'$ respectively;let $Q=I_{2}E\bigcap I_{3}F$,and let $AT$ is internal angle bisectors issued from $A$.we take
$TN\perp BC$ meet $ID'$ at point $N$, and $M$ is midpoint $QI$

show that

$$\angle BAN=\angle CAM$$[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @GEdgar: The OP added a bounty on November 16, while the original question was posted on Octomber 30. Given that in 17 days nobody managed to close his question, I'd say that calling him "sneaky" is a little bit offensive and undeserved.

Comment: The diagram not very good, as it does not show the points $N,M$ that are crucial for the proof. This could be the reason your question received very little attention.